# How can I generate referral link without login interface in PHP?

Tags: php

so it goes like this :

Textfield "what is your name" and a submit button.

Output eg : so your name is ralph!

I want to add a link generator after clicking submit button which will be redirected to the main domain(mysite.com)

so the output will be :
So your name is ralph! here is your Link : domain.com/AbCd123

domain.com/AbCd123 will be redirected to domain.com

anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is too broad and I'm flagging to close. Try actually writing some code and then asking questions when you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the $_GET["VariableName"] from the url of the webpage where you want to process the "name", so, the link, could be something like:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?reference=ralph
```

In the index.php you can retrieve this value, from the $_GET["reference"] variable.